Firebase Storage Permission is kept being denied
My firebase Storage rule is now set as following :
rules_version = '2';

// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}

And my python code for uploading image is :
        self.storage.child(self.uid + '/'+fNameonServer+'.png').put(self.path_here + '/dummy.png')


And here is the error message that I am seeing.
  File "C:\Users\bboyc\PycharmProjects\turtle\.venv\turtle_main.py", line 1140, in uploadImage
    self.storage.child(self.uid + '/'+fNameonServer+'.png').put(self.path_here + '/dummy.png')
  File "C:\Users\bboyc\PycharmProjects\turtle\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebaselite\pyrebaselite.py", line 464, in put
    raise_detailed_error(request_object)
  File "C:\Users\bboyc\PycharmProjects\turtle\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyrebaselite\pyrebaselite.py", line 511, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jost-19f5e.appspot.com/o?name=lKIp1f9k05RmwP6CRWo6qT2Bcir1/imgJustice.png] {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
}

I think it should be storage rule error, since this code worked when the storage rule was only about date, but it does not work even the rule has no regulation. The problem is that I cannot understand what is wrong with this rule.
I want to make storage accessible only if user logged in.

Your security rules matches object paths with the following pattern:

/user/{userId}/{allPaths=**}

But your code isn't using /user in the prefix at all, so the rule would not allow the write to happen.
You should change your code to match the rule, or change the rule to match your code.  If you changed your code, it might look like this:
self.storage.child('/user/' + self.uid + '/'+fNameonServer+'.png')


I changed the rule slightly to match /{userId}/{allPaths=**} {       allow read,write: if request.auth != null;     } and succeeded to upload when there is no if request.auth != null in my rule . However it still gives me 403 error when I want to allow upload when only uploaded.

Why don't you first try with the suggestion I made?  I don't think it's a good idea to always match the first path component against a variable user ID.  That's not going to help you organize non-user content in the future.

I recognized that I only make {userId} folder at Storage, so the tree is look like Storage/userId/Filename.png . So to follow your suggestion I thought changing rule is more adequate. Actually the rule I am using now for test is match /{userId}/{allPaths=**} { allow read,write; } , and the upload is being done so well. But still I cannot understand why allowing by uid is not working.

But I deeply understand that your suggestion is right. I will try your suggestion 100% asap and will leave another comment. Thank you so much.

I just followed your suggestion and changed rules and my code, and failed to make it right. Can you please suggest me what I am missing ?
